# Setting TextViews from an onClick(View v) within an onClick(View v)?

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter

This line will not set, `holder.t1.setText(NewItem);`

If I move it to the parent `onClick`, with a hardcoded string (for testing) it does.

Keep in mind, this is inside a getView method of an `ArrayAdapter`.  I am trying to setText to `ListView` rows.

Edit:

EXPANDED, COMPLETE getView()  -- AS REQUESTED
(Did not have time to edit, will later, sorry!)

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.commentlayout, parent,
                false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.t1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.labelComment);
        holder.t2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.labelDate);
        holder.t3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.labelUser);
        holder.t3.setTypeface(tf);
        holder.t4 = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.labelHelpfulCount);
        holder.t5 = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.labelCommentCount);
        holder.ib1 = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.labelChatIcon);
        holder.ib2 = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.labelCommentFlag);
        holder.rb1 = (RatingBar) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.myCommentsRatingBarSmall);
        holder.b1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bReview1);
        holder.b2 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bReview2);
        holder.b3 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bReview3);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        convertView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(null);
    }

    ReviewObject ro = getItem(position);
    final String item = ro.item;
    final String review = ro.review;
    final String username = ro.username;
    Long date = Long.valueOf(ro.date);
    String rating = ro.ratings;
    String voteCount = ro.voteCount;
    String chatcount = ro.chatCount;
    String cat = ro.cat;

    final ArrayList<String> passing = new ArrayList<String>();
    passing.add(item);
    passing.add(review);
    passing.add(cat);
    passing.add(username);

    String time = "";
    time = DateConvert.dateConvert(Long.valueOf(date));

    holder.t1.setText(review);
    holder.t2.setText(time);
    holder.t3.setText(username);
    holder.t4.setText(voteCount);
    holder.t5.setText(chatcount);
    holder.ib1.setImageResource(R.drawable.updown);
    holder.ib2.setImageResource(R.drawable.comment);
    holder.rb1.setRating(Float.valueOf(rating));

    if (rating.equals("0")) {
        holder.rb1.setEnabled(false);
    }

    holder.b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            String ReviewUser = holder.t3.getText().toString();
            String ReviewWords = holder.t1.getText().toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Comments.class);
            intent.putExtra("comment", ReviewWords);
            intent.putExtra("user", ReviewUser);
            intent.putExtra("item", item);
            getContext().startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    if (!Rateit.username.equals(username)) {

        holder.b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                alertbox.setMessage("Did you like this?");
                alertbox.setNegativeButton("Vote Up",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0,
                                    int arg1) {

                                String VoteTally = holder.t4.getText()
                                        .toString();
                                int ReviewCountInt = Integer
                                        .valueOf(VoteTally) + 1;
                                VoteTally = String.valueOf(ReviewCountInt);
                                holder.t4.setText(VoteTally);

                                new HelpfulTask().execute(passing);
                            }
                        });

                alertbox.setPositiveButton("Vote Down",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {

                                String VoteTally = holder.t4.getText()
                                        .toString();
                                int ReviewCountInt = Integer
                                        .valueOf(VoteTally) - 1;
                                VoteTally = String.valueOf(ReviewCountInt);
                                holder.t4.setText(VoteTally);

                                new UnHelpfulTask().execute(passing);

                            }
                        });

                alertbox.setNeutralButton("Report Spam",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {

                                new SpamTask().execute(passing);

                            }
                        });

                alertbox.show();

            }

        });

    } else {
        holder.b2.setText("Edit");
        holder.b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



            public void onClick(View v) {

                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.editreview);
                dialog.setTitle("Edit Review");
                dialog.show();

                final EditText etEdit = (EditText) dialog
                        .findViewById(R.id.etEditReview);

                etEdit.setText(review);

                Button bInsert = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bInsert);
                bInsert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    public void onClick(View v) {


                        NewItem = etEdit.getText().toString();


                        if (NewItem.equals("")) {

                            Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                                    "Please add something first.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } else {

                            holder.t1.setText(NewItem);
                            passing.add(NewItem);

                            dialog.dismiss();

                            new EditCommentTask().execute(passing);


                        }

                    }
                });

            }
        });

    }

    if (!Rateit.username.equals(username)) {

        holder.b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), OtherProfile.class);
                i.putExtra("userprofile", username);
                getContext().startActivity(i);

            }
        });

    } else {
        holder.b3.setText("Delete");
        holder.b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            public void onClick(View v) {

                AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        getContext());
                alertbox.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete your review?");
                alertbox.setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0,
                                    int arg1) {

                            }
                        });

                alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {

                                new DeleteReviewTask().execute(passing);


                            }
                        });

                alertbox.show();

            }
        });

    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Can you include your code for setting up the viewholder? Also, have you tried referring to the `TextView` you are trying to update directly, without using the `ViewHolder`?

Comment: @Matt I have added that code for you. And yes, I tried without holder but it didn't recognize t1 by itself... Well... like this: t1.setText()

Comment: you might not want to create Dialog every click event. Use instance variable instead. `private Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);`

Comment: @yolapop  Thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't work (assuming I did what you were talking about)

Comment: @KickingLettuce yea sorry i wasn't answering for your question, it was supposed to reduce dialog instance creation

Comment: @yolapop Oh, I misread your question!   Where would you place that code then?

Comment: @KickingLettuce my comment isn't relevant to your question, sorry :)

Comment: Sorry to keep asking questions, but it is still not clear to me. Can you post the entire `getView()`. Also, what is actually happening when you run this code? I am assuming you are getting the `Toast`. Also, what is `NewItem` and where is it defined, i.e. is it a global `String` inside of the adapter? Lastly, what errors/warnings do Eclipse show, take out the suppress warnings line?

Comment: @Matt NO problem.  I put in the entire getView().  ALL of it.  I apologize for not being able to trim it down.  It is the `holder.t1.setText` with the issue again.  I also apologize for my horrible coding habits!  When I run it, nothing happens.  Except, the dialog does dismiss, I get the toast and the task runs correctly.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've said in the above comments, this is the intended function. Since,

> Except, the dialog does dismiss, I get the toast and the task runs correctly.

This is coded into your onClick() here:

```
bInsert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    NewItem = etEdit.getText().toString();

                    if (NewItem.equals("")) {

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                                "Please add something first.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {

                        holder.t1.setText(NewItem);
                        passing.add(NewItem);

                        dialog.dismiss();

                        new EditCommentTask().execute(passing);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Specifically, this is executing:

```
 if (NewItem.equals("")) {
   Toast.makeText(getContext(),
      "Please add something first.",
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

so I am assuming your problem is with `NewItem`, I never see where you actually initialize it, but I am assuming it `.equals("")` since this is executing. Try throwing a `Log.d` or `println()` just below the line `NewItem = etEdit.getText().toString();` to see what the value of `NewItem` is at this point.

Comment: Well, NewItem is not initialized but is declared as a String as field var.  I logged newItem AFTER the setText and it IS infact the new text that was picked up from the EditText field (that the user is editing).  So the problem lies with reaching the Row in the ListView.  It is not setting the text still.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why this isn't working, probably has to do with it being a nested inner class, try commenting out `//holder.t1.setText(NewItem)` and replace with `convertView.findViewById(R.id.labelComment).setText(NewItem);` and see if that helps.  Also, hard code a string in `holder.t1.setText("My string");` that's similar in length to what you have been trying to see if something might be happening with the `TextView` being moved/hidden/obscured by adding the new text

Comment: I hardcoded a string and nothing.  I actually tried that first suggestion before, and it has a problem with `convertView` saying : "Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class and defined in a different method."  So I try to make it Final and that breaks lot of other stuff.

Comment: Another weird thing:  I Log.d `Holder.t1` and it it sees its as `TextView`.  Its almost like it's static (or final?) and it can't change it

Comment: So, this will not help with the `ViewHolder` but might be able to get you going.  Try replacing `holder.t1.setText(NewItem)` with `v.findViewById(R.id.labelComment)` where `v` is the view passed into the `onClick(View v)`. If this works, you should be able to mess around with "that" view that's passed in to find your `ViewHolder` and get it set up for the rest of them by using `v.findViewWithTag()`.  Also, it should log `Holder.t1` as a `TextView` since that is what you defined it as. Let me know how this goes.

Comment: Well, on first attempt... I `Log.d` this `v.findViewById(R.id.labelComment);` it was null. Yeah, I just don't get this one.  I think I need to rework my logic from the beginning and just avoid the way I'm doing it now.